# Optimize SQL query with pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, query-optimization, keyset-pagination

I have a query running against a SQL Server database that is taking over 10 seconds to execute. The table being queried has over 14 million rows.

I want to display the `Text` column from a `Notes` table by a given `ServiceUserId` in date order. There could be thousands of entries so I want to limit the returned values to a manageable level.

```
SELECT Text
FROM   
    (SELECT    
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateDone]) AS RowNum, Text
     FROM      
         Notes
     WHERE     
         ServiceUserId = '6D33B91A-1C1D-4C99-998A-4A6B0CC0A6C2') AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   
    RowNum >= 40 AND RowNum < 60
ORDER BY 
    RowNum
```

Below is the execution plan for the above query.

- Nonclustered Index - nonclustered index on the `ServiceUserId` and `DateDone` columns in ascending order.
- Key lookup - Primary key for the table which is the `NoteId`

[image: Execution plan]

If I run the same query a second time but with different row numbers then I get a response in milliseconds, I assume from a cached execution plan. The query ran for a different `ServiceUserId` will take ~10 seconds though.

Any suggestions for how to speed up this query?

Comment: A backend pagination like this one doesn't make too much sense, unless `DateDone` is a unique value. It doesn't seem to be the case, so the backend pagination will return inconsistent result. Please include a unique criteria for ordering, maybe adding the PK.

Answer (score 1):

### [You should look into Keyset Pagination.](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

**It is far more performant than Rowset Pagination.**

It differs fundamentally from it, in that instead of referencing a particular block of *row numbers*, instead you reference starting point to lookup the index key.

The reason it is much faster is that you don't care about how many rows are before a particular key, you just seek a key and move forward (or backward).

Say you are filtering by a single `ServiceUserId`, ordering by `DateDone`. You need an index as follows (you could leave out the `INCLUDE` if it's too big, it doesn't change the maths very much):

```sql
create index IX_DateDone on Notes (ServiceUserId, DateDone) INCLUDE (TEXT);
```

Now, when you select some rows, instead of giving the start and end *row numbers*, give the *starting key*:

```sql
SELECT TOP (20)
    Text,
    DateDone
FROM
    Notes
WHERE     
    ServiceUserId = '6D33B91A-1C1D-4C99-998A-4A6B0CC0A6C2'
    AND DateDone > @startingDate
ORDER BY 
    DateDone;
```

On the next run, you pass the last `DateDone` value you received. This gets you the next batch.

**The one small downside is that you cannot jump pages.** However, it is much rarer than some may think (from a UI perspective) for a user to want to jump to page 327. So that doesn't really matter.

---

**The key must be unique.** If it is not unique you can't seek to exactly the next row. If you need to use an extra column to guarantee uniqueness, it gets a little more complicated:

```sql
WITH NotesFiltered AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Notes
    WHERE     
        ServiceUserId = '6D33B91A-1C1D-4C99-998A-4A6B0CC0A6C2'
)
SELECT TOP (20)
    Text,
    DateDone
FROM (
    SELECT
        Text,
        DateDone,
        0 AS ordering
    FROM NotesFiltered 
    WHERE
        DateDone = @startingDate AND NoteId > @startingNoteId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Text,
        DateDone,
        1 AS ordering
    FROM NotesFiltered 
    WHERE
        DateDone > @startingDate
) n
ORDER BY 
    ordering, DateDone, NoteId;
```

> **Side Note**
>
> In RDBMSs that support row-value comparisons, the multi-column example could be simplified back to the original code by writing:
>
> ```sql
> WHERE (DateDone, NoteId) > (@startingDate, @startingNoteId)
> ```
>
> Unfortunately SQL Server does not support this currently.
> **Please vote for the [Azure Feedback request for this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894992-add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructo)**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `order by offset fetch` :
it starts from row no x and fetch z next row, which can be parameterized

```
SELECT    
   Text
FROM      
   Notes
WHERE     
   ServiceUserId = '6D33B91A-1C1D-4C99-998A-4A6B0CC0A6C2'
Order by DateDone
OFFSET 40 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

also make sure you have proper index for "DateDone" , maybe include it in the index you already have on "Notes" if you have not yet

you may need to include text column to you index :

```
create index IX_DateDone on Notes(DateDone) INCLUDE (TEXT,ServiceUserId)
```

however be noticed that adding such huge column to the index will effect your insert/update efficiency and of course It will need disk space

Comment: This is the query format I was originally using. It has a similar execution time to the query in my question of ~10 seconds. There is already a Non-Clustered index on 'DateDone' what column were you suggesting it be combined with?

Comment: the query plan should look different and simplified , paste the query plan with this query into https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and lets see what we can do

Comment: but to answer your question include ServiceUserId and text on DoneDate index

Comment: Thank you for the link. Here is the query plan as requested: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1hgi00zd

Comment: @Tomsmith I had updated my query to be order by DateDone  try the updated one

Comment: however based on the execution plan , 98% of cost of this query is "Key lookup" which the index would solve the issue

Comment: There was negligible difference ordering by the DateDone. I am unable to add the Text column to the index, It is an nvarchar(Max) Data Type that allows nulls. Is the allow nulls option a reason why I couldn't add it to the index? There will be cases where it is not just the Text I am interested, potentially other fields, would these need to be included in the Index as well?

Comment: you should be able to include it into the index , see my example in the answer

Comment: @Tomsmith just out of curiosity , did you get any success?