# How to apply DENSE_RANK() to records ordered by multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a SQL stored procedure that for each `AliasName` it will retrieve me `MasterNames` it's associated with in the `NameAssociations` table, which contains `AliasNameId`, `MasterNameId`, and `MatchRank`, and `StatusCode` columns. I'll be using the stored procedure for server-side paging the data in C#, so I'd like the `startRow` `endRow` part to stay the same.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NameAssociationsGetNameAssociations]
    @StartRow INT = 1,
    @EndRow INT = 1
AS
    WITH result_set AS (
        SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY an.Id) AS rowNum,        
        an.Id as AliasId, an.AliasName,
        mn.Id as MasterId, mn.MasterName, mn.CodeId, mn.RowUpdateVersion AS ConcurrencyToken, na.MatchRank
    FROM
        NameAssociations na 
        INNER JOIN AliasNames an
        ON na.AliasNameId = an.Id 
        INNER JOIN MasterNames mn
        ON na.MasterNameId = mn.Id 
    WHERE
        na.StatusCode = 0
    ) 
    SELECT
        rowNum, 
        AliasId as Id, AliasName,
        MasterId as Id, MasterName, CodeId, ConcurrencyToken, MatchRank
    FROM
        result_set
    WHERE
        rowNum BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
```

This procedure works and retrieves rows numbered correctly:

| rowNum | Id | AliasName | Id | MasterName | CodeId | ConcurrencyToken | MatchRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | BName | 34 | SomeName1 | 2 | 0x0000021 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | DName | 21 | SomeName2 | 3 | 0x0000003 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | DName | 2 | SomeName3 | 1 | 0x00000A2 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | DName | 40 | SomeName4 | 1 | 0x00000B4 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 | AName | 11 | SomeName5 | 1 | 0x000005B | 1 |

So basically, I get a list of `MasterNames` for every `AliasName`.

But the rows are not ordered in the way I would like them to be, which is by `AliasName` ASC, `Id` (of alias) ASC, and `MatchRank` ASC, which would look like this:

| rowNum | Id | AliasName | Id | MasterName | CodeId | ConcurrencyToken | MatchRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | AName | 11 | SomeName5 | 1 | 0x000005B | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | BName | 34 | SomeName1 | 2 | 0x0000021 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | DName | 2 | SomeName3 | 1 | 0x00000A2 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | DName | 21 | SomeName2 | 3 | 0x0000003 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 | DName | 40 | SomeName4 | 1 | 0x00000B4 | 3 |

You can see the names of aliases are ordered alphabetically, and then the associated masters were reordered so the `MatchRank` is in ASC order. All of this while the `rowNum` is correct, which is what I've been having trouble with attaining.

I've tried doing `PARTITION BY an.Id ORDER BY an.AliasName ASC, an.Id ASC, na.MatchRank ASC`, but I must be misunderstanding what `ORDER BY` does in this case because the results come out wrong. The results look like it ordered the records only by `MatchRank` ASC and partitioned by it. I'm expecting it to order the data by those three columns, and then partition it by the `an.Id`.

How can I write the query so that the output result looks like the second example of table? I hope this was all clear.

Comment: `PARTITION BY` is basically a `GROUP BY` for aggregates, so the numbering restarts for every new `Id`. I think you want `ORDER BY AliasName, AliasId, MatchRank` with no `PARTITION`. The ordering of the actual output rows is dependent on an outer `ORDER BY` which you do not have, so theoretically the rows could come back in a different order from the rownumbering result. Re paging, you might find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66484823/14868997

Comment: Your query and example output don't match up logically.  The `partition by an.id` would restart the ranking for each new `id` value.  I think you actually have an `order by` here?

Comment: Yes, that was meant to be an `ORDER BY an.Id`.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring what looks like a transcription/obfuscation error in your script that actually renders your SQL as invalid (`dense_rank` must have an `order by`), I think your solution is actually pretty simple.

The `dense_rank` function uses the values in the `order by` to determine which records get the same ranking value, so if you want to sort the output by the `AliasName`, but also want to make sure records with the same `AliasName` but different `id` values (not sure why this would be possible, but defensive coding is generally a good practice), you just need to include *both* values in your `order by`, in the order that you want to apply sorting.  In your case this looks like the following minimal solution:

#### Query

```
declare @t table(id int, AliasName varchar(10), val int);
insert into @t values (1,'b',1),(2,'c',2),(2,'c',3),(2,'cc',4),(22,'c',5),(3,'a',6);

select *
      ,dense_rank() over (order by id) as rid
      ,dense_rank() over (order by AliasName, id) as rAliasName
from @t;
```

---

#### Output

| id | AliasName | val | rid | rAliasName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a | 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | c | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | c | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 22 | c | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | cc | 4 | 2 | 5 |